Electron Forge: show ESLint problems in terminal
I have an electron-forge project. I want eslint problems to show in the terminal via webpack. I added the ESLintPlugin, but did not manage to configure it to show the problems in the terminal. The only way I managed to get it to show them is as an overlay over the app's UI, which is not what I want. This can be turned off with { emitError: false, emitWarning: false }, but I couldn't find a way to get the problems to show in the terminal.
The webpack plugins config:
export const plugins = [
  new ESLintPlugin({
    extensions: ['ts', 'tsx'],
  }),
  // ... Other plugins
]

The ESLint problems shown over the app's UI:

Any help would be appreciated.
